# Moderation: moderation where there is no main effect for moderator on DV

Tags: interaction

I have run a moderation analysis using PROCESS. The model examines whether 'time' moderates the (IV) intention- (DV) B5 relationship.

My model is significant overall. Intention and the interaction term are significant, but time is not a significant predictor of B5.

I am trying to understand whether moderation can occur if there is no main effect for the moderator on the DV (but the interaction term is a significant predictor.

The output is linked below.

Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEFLA.png

Comment: It would help if you showed us the results.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the link to the output would be viewable. I've added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. One way this can happen is if the effects are crossed. For example suppose we had categorical independent variables, each 0 or 1 and suppose all cells are the same size. Then suppose we had:

```
IV1 = 0   IV2 = 0 MEAN DV = 100
IV1 = 1   IV2 = 0 MEAN DV  = 0
IV1 = 0   IV2 = 1 MEAN DV =  0
IV1 = 1   IV2 = 1 MEAN DV = 100
```

So, the main effect of IV1 is 0, the main effect of IV2 is 0. But the interaction is huge.

Similar stuff can happen with continuous IVs and I have seen it happen in "real life".